# SortedSet fold type mismatch

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold, sortedset

I have this code:

```
def distinct(seq: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] =
  seq.fold(SortedSet[Int]()) ((acc, i) => acc + i)
```

I want to iterate over `seq`, delete duplicates (keep the first number) and keep order of the numbers. My idea was to use a `SortedSet` as an acc.

But I am getting:

> Type mismatch:
> Required: String
> Found: Any

How to solve this?  (I also don't know how to convert `SortedSet` to `Seq` in the final iteration as I want `distinct` to return `seq`)

p.s. without using standard `seq` `distinct` method

[Online code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Shg7YciyTpycvLnDajxn4w)

Comment: `seq.foldLeft(SortedSet[Int]())(_+_).toSeq` You'll find that `fold()` is more restrictive in its type profile. Note that a `SortedList()` won't "keep order of the numbers" as you require.

Comment: @jwvh oh, sorted != ordered :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `fold` if you try to accumulate something with different type than container (`SortedSet` != `Int`) in your case. Look at signature `fold`:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

it takes accumulator with type `A1` and combiner function `(A1, A1) => A1` which combines two `A1` elements.

In your case is better to use `foldLeft` which takes accumulator with different type than container:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

it accumulates some `B` value using *seed* `z` and combiner from `B` and `A` to `B`.

In your case I would like to use `LinkedHashSet` it keeps the order of added elements and remove duplicates, look:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

def distinct(seq: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
  seq.foldLeft(mutable.LinkedHashSet.empty[Int])(_ + _).toSeq
}
distinct(Seq(7, 2, 4, 2, 3, 0)) // ArrayBuffer(7, 2, 4, 3, 0)
distinct(Seq(0, 0, 0, 0)) // ArrayBuffer(0)
distinct(Seq(1, 5, 2, 7)) // ArrayBuffer(1, 5, 2, 7)
```

and after folding just use `toSeq`

be careful, lambda `_ + _` is just syntactic sugar for combiner:

```
(linkedSet, nextElement) => linkedSet + nextElement
```

Comment: why the fold left? Cant you just use `apply` of `LinkedHashSet`? i.e. `def distinct(seq: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = mutable.LinkedHashSet(seq:_*).toSeq`, and why not use `seq.distinct` in the first place? As I can see in the source-code, it should preserve order

Comment: why `SortedSet[Int] -> SortedSet.empty[Int]` is a mistake? I was initializing an empty set to be passed into foldLeft as acc?

Answer (score 0):

I would just call `distinct` on your `Seq`. You can see in the source-code of `SeqLike`, that `distinct` will just traverse the `Seq` und skip already seen data:

```
  def distinct: Repr = {
    val b = newBuilder
    val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
    for (x <- this) {
      if (!seen(x)) {
        b += x
        seen += x
      }
    }
    b.result
  }
```